# BundleConfig scripts not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, backbone.js

I'm using the following `BundleCollection` items on my ASP MVC 4 site (first time using MVC 4). I'm trying to load jQuery and Backbone.js, but according to Chrome's console this is working properly.

Below is the .js file I'm using right now. When I first load the page I get the following error

[image]

If I comment out that line, then I get this error on the next line

[image]

That seems to tell me that, even though I am not getting any errors, Backbone and jQuery are not loading properly (although I could be wrong).

**BundleConfig**

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/BackboneApps").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/SliderApp.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jsMVC").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/underscore.js",
                    "~/Scripts/backbone.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
}
```

**Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jsMVC")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/BackboneApps")
</head>
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
    <h3>SPX Allocation: <span id="SpxAllocPercentage"></span></h3>
        <!-- "slider" is a jquery slider -->
    <div id="slider"></div>

    <!-- "sliderVal" displays the slider's position. It receives the value via model. -->
    <input type="text" id="sliderVal" value="0"/>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the rendered HTML. Immediately noticed that Backbone is missing.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/SliderApp.js"></script>

</head>
```

When I checked the console again, seems I was wrong and there are these two error regarding Backbone and Underscore

[image]

Comment: Be careful with the bundling to ensure that each file is terminated with a `;`, and possibly a line break. I've had issues in the past where the files are simply concatenated together. If the end of one command meets the start of another, you'll get weird errors like this.

Comment: I'd also consider jslinting your files to see if there are any other javascript errors

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just noticed that Backbone/Underscore were missing from the rendered HTML. Updated the post.

Comment: Have you tried putting the jquery bundle first?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `bundles/jsMVC` and manually include the 2 `.js` files?

Comment: So if I put the `jsMVC` bundle last (1. jquery 2. jqueryui 3. jsMVC) then, if I comment out the `.slider()` line Backbone loads just fine. However, I am still getting the first error on '$("#slider").slider()' in the 'SliderApp.js' file. Any idea why the slider doesn't work?

Comment: Actually, I think the slider issue might be separate from the the bundle issue. If you guys want to offer as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the other bundles include jquery ( defined twice ) it is possible to see errors like this. Start by loading one bundle at a time and view page source to verify that the files in the bundle has been included. Repeat for each until one bundle loads with missing files.